# Get different error DTO via WebFlux Client

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm calling an API which on success returns Employee DTO which looks something like this

```json
{  
   "id": "guid1",
   "name": "John",
   "designation": "Software Engineer"
}
```

In case of error (4xx, 5xx), it returns an error DTO which returns something like this

```json
{
    "requestId": "guid2", 
    "errorMessage": "some error message",
    "appErrorCode": 1235
}
```

I have DTOs for both of these responses.

Now, I am writing WebFlux client using this API

```java
        webClient.post()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(Mono.just(employee), PostEmployeeRequest.class)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(
                        httpStatus -> httpStatus == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                        clientResponse -> {
                            //  <-- How do I parse the error request body??
                            // Need to write custom logic here, depending upon error response
                           Mono.error(new InvalidInputException(errorMessage));
                        })
                .bodyToMono(PostEmployeeResponseDto.class)
                .block();
```

Comment: `bodyToMono` on your `clientResponse`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
return clientResponse.bodyToMono(MyErrorDto.class).flatMap(errorDTO -> Mono.error(new InvalidInputException(errorDTO)))
```

inside the .onStatus()